# Upgrade to Ubuntu 18.04 ( libmpi_mpifh.so.12: cannot open)

Tags: upgrade

I have upgraded my distro from ubuntu 16.04 to ubuntu 18.04. When I am trying to run `pw.x` ( executable), it gives the following error:

> pw.x: error while loading shared libraries: libmpi_mpifh.so.12: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: What is the `pw.x`? Where we can get it? Is it possible to compile it again on upgraded system? Please add output of `which pw.x`, `dpkg -S $(which pw.x)`, `apt-cache policy quantum-espresso` to the question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49412080/libmpi-mpifh-so-12-cannot-open

Comment: @Norbet: it isnot possible to compile the quantum espresso (pw.x) in the upgraded distro. It was working perfeectly in the old distro. The output is the one i wrote up.